# Keyframes not working in IE 10,11

Tags: internet-explorer, css-animations

http://www.restaurantplacement.com.php56-22.dfw3-1.websitetestlink.com/

Here is the website link where I have it working in all browsers except for IE 10,11. It scrolls from left to right.

Comment: Put in some code, always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the definition of your keyfames. The standard syntax is `@keyframes name` not `@keyfames "name"`. Hence, I recommend you to remove the quotes `" "` from all your `@keframes` names.
They are defined in the file 
http://www.restaurantplacement.com.php56-22.dfw3-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/style.css

remove quotes to make them be.

```
 @keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
 margin-left: -8455px;
}

}

@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
 100% {
 margin-left: -8455px;
 }

 }

@-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
 margin-left: -8455px;
}

 }

 @-ms-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
 margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
 margin-left: -8455px;
} 

}

@-o-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
  margin-left: -8455px;
}

}
```

I cannot be sure this is the problem. Because I cannot edit the file and reload the page (if it is possible, i do not know), I have not been able to verify if it solves the problem.
However, For website like this, it is always better to give a little code (that you think has relation with the problem). I took at least 20 minutes to search for what could be the problem in your website files. It would have been easier if you had included the content of this file.
Hope it works.

Comment: thank you! i even read this somewhere but forgot i didnt remove them!